# How can I safely install an outlet in my fireplace?

Tags: receptacle, fireplace

I want to install an LED lighting display in my otherwise unused wood-burning fireplace but do not want to run an extension cord through the doors and into the firebox. Is there such a thing as a 120VAC outlet made from refractory materials that can installed somewhere within a firebox?

Comment: Do you intend to use the fireplace again after this is installed?  You say it's unused - if that's the case, why ask about refractory materials?

Comment: I get the point (I used to have a complete stereo in my wood fireplace box--the bass resonance was awesome), but to set up something permanent like that seems to violate all good sense.

Comment: I'd like the option to use it as a proper fireplace in the future... I understand the process of fully decommissioning a fireplace, and stating as much, if selling the home. I have a kiln with all sorts electrical protrusions through the walls so it seems that there'd be some technology for getting electricity safely through firebox walls.

Comment: Would need more info on your plans, but the wire to power your LED light can probably be pretty fine, maybe running just that in would be enough.  Another idea is rechargeable battery power, my next door neighbor has an outdoor LED arrangement that he powers with an 18v Milwaukee tool battery (Connection using alligator clips).  The LEDs use so little power that he only charges the battery every 3weeks.

Comment: I'd second Tyson's battery recommendation.  Given how little power LEDs draw, I'd strongly consider that vs breaching your firebox.

Comment: Is it an insert, or a masonry fireplace? Does it have a blower?

Comment: It is an old semi-insert type of wood-burning fireplace built by the tract home builder in the 70s; the firebox is made with refractory "panels". There is no blower, nor is there a gas outlet in the box or anywhere near it.